# Cannot make Scrollspy Bootstrap work

Tags: jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I am designing a single page website and want the fixed nav links to change colour whenever the user scrolls to the specified location. Seems pretty easy to do, I thought it was pretty easy to do, but I am having problems making it work.

I only downloaded the Scrollspy JS Plugin, as I am not using the Twitter Bootstrap CSS. I just require the Scrollspy Plugin.

Could you check this jsFiddle and provide some guidance? I have already checked out the documentation [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy), but I've had no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

http://jsfiddle.net/xjTpk/28/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the serious issues with your use of JSFiddle<sup>**1**</sup>, and the typographic errors<sup>**2**</sup>, the principle things wrong are

1. You need the .nav class on the `<ul>` in the navbar, and
2. The `#welcome` is not an existing element, causing a JS error.

Here's a fixed demo:

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjTpk/48/)

Oh, and you don't need both data-api and js to initialize the plugin; choose one.

<sub>**1** Loading Bootstrap 2.0.2 + 2.0.4 at the same time; trying to include a `<body>` in the html panel</sub>

<sub>**2** Using upperCamelCase on a function that doesn't need it: `scrollSpy()`;</sub>

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for pointing out my weaknesses. Best way to learn :). It was my first time using jsFiddle. But I'll get the hang of it.

Comment: Please resize browser when scroll bar is in between and then check selected item in menu bar... its not working with browser resize :(

Comment: @ChinmayeeG I don't see how handling viewport changes is relevant to resolving issue of OP. Handling your remark would involve extending the ScrollSpy plugin's functionality, which I don't think is in the scope of the question. However, I acknowledge the issue you point out and encourage you to post it as a separate question elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Key thing you are missing is you have to have a "nav" class on the ul element (or some other parent element) as that is used in the scrollspy code as part of a selector.

I couldn't get yours to work for some reason but here is a simplified example:
http://jsfiddle.net/UWzeD/5/

Answer (score 0):

Your ul needs a nav class, but most important for scrollspy to work properly is that your target needs to be one level about the ul.  Otherwise I've found that scrollspy doesn't work.